# Showing pieces of HTML on WPF Form

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I'd like to show pieces of HTML on my form. I've looked at a few examples online regarding using a webform or document layout, etc and nothing works for me.

We have a system on our website where a user can enter a notification using a Real Text Editor (CKEditor). The message is saved in the DB and a WPF application on all the computers in the office should display the message.

I would like to support HTML in my WPF program. The HTML isn't in a page, it's a piece of HTML in the db that needs to be displayed in its rendered form on the WPF application.

For example, if someone enters `<img src="http://www.google.com/google.jpg" />` it will show the image in the wpf application when I retrieve it from the database and show it on the form.

What's the best way to do this?

P.S. I can't use a web browser because the Windows has "AllowTranparency" set to true.

Comment: Have you looked at a [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) control?

Comment: Yeah I made an edit. The parent window has allowtransparency so I can't use the webBrowser

Answer (score 7):

Add a WebBrowser control to your application:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfBrowser.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <WebBrowser Height="311" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="webBrowser1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="503" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And then use the `NavigateToString` of the `WebBrowser` to load the page from your html string:

```
webBrowser1.NavigateToString("<html><head></head><body>First row<br>Second row</body></html>");
```

Comment: What's weird is I did that. Your example works but on my form the browser doesn't show anything, it's completely white but when I right click it I can view source and see the HTML you put above.

Comment: @Eitan: Please give example of what code you used: xaml and code behind. I called `NavigateToString` in MainWindow constructor right after `InitializeComponent();` and it works.

Comment: Yeah I figure out why it didn't work, I have an animation that fades the program in. In order to do this I need to set Allow Transparency to true. When I do the web browser it doesn't work when AllowTransparency = true

Comment: Sadly, even in 2016, this old non-WPF-native component is still the easiest and most sane options for displaying HTML in WPF applications.